# Remove a line/block from QTextEdit

Tags: qt, qtextedit, qtextdocument

I'm struggling with block/line removal from `QTextEdit`. Code below should(?) work but it ends up in infinite loop for some unknown to me reason. I have a suspicion that `next()` and `previous()` are not welcome if `QTextDocument` is being edited.

```
QTextBlock block = document()->begin();
while (block.isValid()) {
    if (to_do_or_not_to_do(block)) {
        QTextCursor cursor(block);
        cursor.select(QTextCursor::BlockUnderCursor);
        cursor.removeSelectedText();
    }
    block = block.next();
}
```

Iterating using `QTextDocument::findBlockByNumber()` and deleting block in the same way as above didn't worked either.

I would appreciate if someone could point me into right direction on how to iterate trough all the blocks and remove them if needed.

*P.S.

In my particular case one block = one line.

Qt 4.6.2, Ubuntu 10.04 x64*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing it a little works for me:

```
while (block.isValid()) {
    if (to_do_or_not_to_do(block)) {
        QTextCursor cursor(block);
        block = block.next();
        cursor.select(QTextCursor::BlockUnderCursor);
        cursor.removeSelectedText();
    }
    else
        block = block.next();
}
```

Comment: Correct. Because obviously `removeSelectedText()` kills the block, and `next()` does not work anymore. Thanks! :)